What might be the issue to this error? I have tried using grit command and tried downgrading openai still it won't work?
I am currently working on the chat module for the parsed resume and I am using chain but I am getting the error below.
{ "detail": "Failed to get the answer \n\nYou tried to access openai.ChatCompletion, but this is no longer supported in openai>=1.0.0 - see the README at https://github.com/openai/openai-python for the API.\n\nYou can run openai migrate to automatically upgrade your codebase to use the 1.0.0 interface. \n\nAlternatively, you can pin your installation to the old version, e.g. pip install openai==0.28\n\nA detailed migration guide is available here: https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742\n" }
below is the code related to my project
import os
import shutil
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile, HTTPException, File
import json

from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

from langchain_setup import create_vector_store, get_chain
import parser
from parser import ExtractInformationFromResume, PyPDFLoader, PdfToText
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

from pydantic import BaseModel


class QueryRequest(BaseModel):
    user_id: str
    question: str


app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["http://localhost:5173"],  # Adjust this to your frontend origin
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],  # Allow all methods (GET, POST, etc.)
    allow_headers=["*"],  # Allow all headers
)

resume_chains = {}


# API endpoint to upload PDF file
@app.post("/upload-file/")
async def upload_resume(user_id, file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    if not file.filename.endswith(".pdf"):
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Invalid file type. Only PDFs are allowed.")

    # Define directories
    uploads = "backend/uploads"
    parsed_resume = "backend/parsed_resume"
    os.makedirs(uploads, exist_ok=True)
    os.makedirs(parsed_resume, exist_ok=True)

    # Save the uploaded file
    file_location = f"backend/uploads/{file.filename}"
    try:
        with open(file_location, "wb") as buffer:
            shutil.copyfileobj(file.file, buffer)
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=f"Error saving file: {str(e)}")

    # Extract text from the PDF
    try:
        loader = PyPDFLoader(file_location)
        pages = loader.load_and_split()

        if len(pages) == 0:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="No content found in the PDF.")

        resume_text = pages[0].page_content  # Process the first page
        print(resume_text)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=f"Error parsing PDF: {str(e)}")

    # Get extracted information from the resume text
    try:
        parsed_resume = ExtractInformationFromResume(resume_text)

        with open(f"backend/parsed_resume/{file.filename.split('.')[0]}.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(parsed_resume.dict(), f, indent=4)
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=f"Failed to parse the file: {e}")

    try:
        parsed_text = json.dumps(parsed_resume.dict())
        vector_store = create_vector_store(parsed_text)
        chain = get_chain(vector_store)
        resume_chains[user_id] = chain
        print(resume_chains)
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=f"Failed to create vector store and chain: {e}")

    response = {
        "message": f"Resume uploaded and processed successfully. This is the user_id {user_id}",
        "information": parsed_resume.dict()
    }
    return JSONResponse(status_code=200, content=response)


@app.post("/chat/")
async def ask_question(query: QueryRequest):
    '''Endpoint to ask questions about the resume'''
    user_id = query.user_id
    question = query.question

    print(f"Resume Chains: {resume_chains}")

    if user_id not in resume_chains:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail='Resume not uploaded for the user.')
    chain = resume_chains[user_id]
    try:
        response = chain({'question': question})
        answer = response['answer']
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=f'Failed to get the answer {e}')

    return {'answer': answer}

import os
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

# Initialize OpenAI LLM
llm = OpenAI(
    openai_api_key=os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY'),
    temperature=0.5,  # Adjust as needed
    model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo-0125"
)

# Initialize embeddings
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key='sk-proj-xxx')

def create_vector_store(text: str):
    """
    Create a FAISS vector store from the given text.
    """
    text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(
        separator="\n",
        chunk_size=1000,
        chunk_overlap=200,
        length_function=len,
    )
    texts = text_splitter.split_text(text)
    vector_store = FAISS.from_texts(texts, embeddings)
    return vector_store

def get_chain(vector_store):
    """
    Create a Conversational Retrieval Chain.
    """
    memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", return_messages=True)
    chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
        llm=llm,
        retriever=vector_store.as_retriever(),
        memory=memory,
        verbose=True
    )
    return chain



well, you've just given everyone your openai api key, you should take down this post and revoke the key for security

@Apollo-Roboto Thank you for pointing out. But apart from that can you help me with the problem that I am encountering with?
